# Having an issue with MPI_GATHER/MPI_GATHERV in F90 with derived data types

Tags: mpi, fortran90

I have a task in which I will have several data types together; character, several integers, and a double precision value, which represent a solution to a problem.

At the moment, I have a "toy" F90 program, that uses MPI with random numbers and a contrived character string for each processor.  I want to have a data type that has the character and the double precision random number together.

I will use MPI_REDUCE to get the minimum value for the double precision values.  I will have the data type for each process brought together to the root (rank = 0) via the MPI_GATHERV function.

My goal is to match up the minimum value from the random values to the data type.  That would be the final answer.  I have tried all sort of ideas up to this point, but to no avail.  I end up with "forrtl: severe SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred".

Now I have looked at several of the other postings too.  For instance, I cannot use the "use mpif.h" statement on this particular system.

But, at last, here is the code:

```
program fredtype
  implicit none
  include '/opt/apps/intel15/mvapich2/2.1/include/mpif.h'



  integer rank,size,ierror,tag,status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),i,np,irank
  integer blocklen(2),type(2),num,rcount(4)
  double precision :: x,aout
  character(len=4) :: y

  type, BIND(C) :: mytype
     double precision :: x,aout,test
     character :: y
  end type mytype

  type(mytype) :: foo,foobag(4)
  integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: disp(2),base


  call MPI_INIT(ierror)

 call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)

  aout = 99999999999.99

  call random_seed()
  call random_number(x)



  if(rank.eq.0)y="dogs"
  if(rank.eq.1)y="cats"
  if(rank.eq.2)y="tree"
  if(rank.eq.3)y="woof"

  print *,rank,x,y


  call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(foo%x,disp(1),ierror)
  call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(foo%y,disp(2),ierror)

  base = disp(1)
 call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)

  aout = 99999999999.99

  call random_seed()
  call random_number(x)



  if(rank.eq.0)y="dogs"
  if(rank.eq.1)y="cats"
  if(rank.eq.2)y="tree"
  if(rank.eq.3)y="woof"

  print *,rank,x,y


  call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(foo%x,disp(1),ierror)
  call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(foo%y,disp(2),ierror)

  base = disp(1)
 call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)

  aout = 99999999999.99

  call random_seed()
  call random_number(x)



  if(rank.eq.0)y="dogs"
  if(rank.eq.1)y="cats"
  if(rank.eq.2)y="tree"
  if(rank.eq.3)y="woof"

  print *,rank,x,y


  call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(foo%x,disp(1),ierror)
  call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(foo%y,disp(2),ierror)

  base = disp(1)
  disp(2) = disp(2) - base

  blocklen(1) = 1
  blocklen(2) = 1

  type(1) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
  type(2) = MPI_CHARACTER


  call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(2,blocklen,disp,type,foo,ierror)
  call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(foo,ierror)




       call MPI_REDUCE(x,aout,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_MIN,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,i\
error)

       call MPI_GATHER(num,1,MPI_INT,rcount,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD)
       call MPI_GATHERV(foo,num,type,foobag,rcount,disp,type,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD)


       if(rank.eq.0)then
           print *,'fin ',aout

          end if




end program fredtype
```

Thank you for any help.
Sincerely,
Erin

Comment: Just a sanity check, your actual code doesn't repeat the middle block 3 times as the version you posted here, right? I don't think that would cause a problem, but that's definitely strange.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is definitely too confusing for me to try to fully fix it. So let's just assume that you have your type `mytype` defined as follow:

```
type, bind(C) :: mytype
    double precision :: x, aout, test
    character(len=4) :: y
end type mytype
```

(Rk: I've add `len=4` to the definition of `y` as it seemed to be missing from your original code. I might be wrong it that and if so, just adjust `blocklen(2)` in the subsequent code accordingly)

Now let's assume that you only want to transfer the `x` and `y` fields of your variables of type `mytype`. For this, you'll need to create an appropriated derived MPI type using first `MPI_Type_create_struct()` to define the basic types and their location into your structure, and then `MPI_Type_create_resized()` to define the true extent and lower bound of the type, including holes.

The tricky part is usually to evaluate what the lower bound and extent of your Fortran type is. Here, as you include into the fields that you transfer the first and last of them, and as you added `bind(C)`, you can just use `MPI_Type_get_extend()` to get these informations. However, if you hadn't included `x` or `y` (which are first and last fields of the type) into the MPI data type, `MPI_Type_get_extent()` wouldn't have return what you would have needed. So I'll propose you an alternative (slightly more cumbersome) approach which will, I believe, always work:

```
integer :: ierror, typefoo, tmptypefoo
integer :: blocklen(2), types(2)
type(mytype) :: foobag(4)
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: disp(2), lb, extent

call MPI_Get_address( foobag(1), lb, ierror )
call MPI_Get_address( foobag(1)%x, disp(1), ierror )
call MPI_Get_address( foobag(1)%y, disp(2), ierror )
call MPI_Get_address( foobag(2), extent, ierror )
disp(1) = MPI_Aint_diff( disp(1), lb )
disp(2) = MPI_Aint_diff( disp(2), lb )
extent = MPI_Aint_diff( extent, lb )
lb = 0

blocklen(1) = 1
blocklen(2) = 4

types(1) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
types(2) = MPI_CHARACTER

call MPI_Type_create_struct( 2, blocklen, disp, types, tmptypefoo, ierror )
call MPI_Type_create_resized( tmptypefoo, lb, extent, typefoo, ierror )
call MPI_Type_commit( typefoo, ierror )
```

So as you can see, `lb` serves as base address for the displacements into the structure, and the type extent is computed by using the relative addresses of two consecutive elements of an array of type `mytype`.
Then, we create an intermediary MPI data type `tmptypefoo` which only contains the information about the actual data we will transfer, and we extent it with information about the actual lower bound and extent of the Fortran type into `typefoo`. Finally, only this last one needs to be committed as only it will serve for data transfers.

Comment: Wow!  This is awesome!  Thank you very much.  May I ask one more question, please:  then I pass typefoo in the MPI_GATHERV function, please? Thanks again.